# Geo Django 3.2 django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such function: lwgeom_version

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, geodjango

I was trying to fetch the list of Dentists that are nearby from a user's current location.

users' current location(latitude and longitude) is sent through query parameters.

The dentist's location is saved in a model called location where the id of the dentist is the foreign key and unique identifier.
I have used the PointField field from drf_extra_fields.geo_fields in LocationSerializer

I'm using python 3.10 and Django 3.2.8

**Model**

```
class Location(models.Model):
    id = models.OneToOneField(Dentist, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    location = models.PointField(srid=4326)
```

**Serializer**

```
from drf_extra_fields.geo_fields import PointField

class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    location = PointField()
    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = ['id', 'location']
```

**View**

```
class NearByDentistView(APIView):
    def get(self,request):
        longitude = float(self.request.query_params.get('longitude'))
        latitude  = float(self.request.query_params.get('latitude'))
        user_location = Point(latitude,longitude,srid=4326)
        queryset = Location.objects.filter(location__distance_lte=(user_location, D(km=100)))

        serializer = LocationSerializer(queryset,many=True)
    
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**Response**

```
Internal Server Error: /api/v1/user/dentist/nearby/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\CODES\Django\SMILE_BACKEND\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 82, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "d:\CODES\Django\SMILE_BACKEND\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 421, in execute      
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such function: lwgeom_version

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\CODES\Django\SMILE_BACKEND\venv\lib\site-packages\asgiref\sync.py", line 482, in thread_handler
    raise exc_info[1]
  File "d:\CODES\Django\SMILE_BACKEND\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 38, in inner
    response = await get_response(request)
  File "d:\CODES\Django\SMILE_BACKEND\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 233, in _get_response_async
    response = await wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "d:\CODES\Django\SMILE_BACKEND\venv\lib\site-packages\asgiref\sync.py", line 444, in __call__
    ret = await asyncio.wait_for(future, timeout=None)
  File "C:\Users\amanu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 408, in wait_for
    return await fut
  File "C:\Users\amanu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 52, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "d:\CODES\Django\SMILE_BACKEND\venv\lib\site-packages\asgiref\sync.py", line 486, in thread_handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\CODES\Django\SMILE_BACKEND\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\CODES\Django\SMILE_BACKEND\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\CODES\Django\SMILE_BACKEND\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "d:\CODES\Django\SMILE_BACKEND\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "d:\CODES\Django\SMILE_BACKEND\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "d:\CODES\Django\SMILE_BACKEND\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\CODES\Django\SMILE_BACKEND\users\views.py", line 470, in get
    return Response(serializer.data)
  File "d:\CODES\Django\SMILE_BACKEND\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 745, in data
    ret = super().data
  File "d:\CODES\Django\SMILE_BACKEND\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 246, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "d:\CODES\Django\SMILE_BACKEND\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 663, in to_representation
    return [
  File "d:\CODES\Django\SMILE_BACKEND\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 280, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "d:\CODES\Django\SMILE_BACKEND\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1324, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "d:\CODES\Django\SMILE_BACKEND\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 51, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "d:\CODES\Django\SMILE_BACKEND\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1162, in execute_sql
    sql, params = self.as_sql()
  File "d:\CODES\Django\SMILE_BACKEND\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 528, in as_sql
    where, w_params = self.compile(self.where) if self.where is not None else ("", [])
  File "d:\CODES\Django\SMILE_BACKEND\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 445, in compile
    sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)
  File "d:\CODES\Django\SMILE_BACKEND\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\where.py", line 81, in as_sql
    sql, params = compiler.compile(child)
  File "d:\CODES\Django\SMILE_BACKEND\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 445, in compile
    sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)
  File "d:\CODES\Django\SMILE_BACKEND\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\models\lookups.py", line 330, in as_sql
    sql, params = compiler.compile(distance_expr.resolve_expression(compiler.query))
  File "d:\CODES\Django\SMILE_BACKEND\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 443, in compile
    sql, params = vendor_impl(self, self.connection)
  File "d:\CODES\Django\SMILE_BACKEND\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\models\functions.py", line 297, in as_sqlite
    return super().as_sql(compiler, connection, **extra_context)
  File "d:\CODES\Django\SMILE_BACKEND\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\models\functions.py", line 52, in as_sql
    function = connection.ops.spatial_function_name(self.name)
  File "d:\CODES\Django\SMILE_BACKEND\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\backends\base\operations.py", line 115, in spatial_function_name
    if func_name in self.unsupported_functions:
  File "d:\CODES\Django\SMILE_BACKEND\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "d:\CODES\Django\SMILE_BACKEND\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\backends\spatialite\operations.py", line 84, in unsupported_functions
    if not self.lwgeom_version():
  File "d:\CODES\Django\SMILE_BACKEND\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\backends\spatialite\operations.py", line 168, in lwgeom_version
    return self._get_spatialite_func('lwgeom_version()')
  File "d:\CODES\Django\SMILE_BACKEND\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\backends\spatialite\operations.py", line 152, in _get_spatialite_func
    cursor.execute('SELECT %s' % func)
  File "d:\CODES\Django\SMILE_BACKEND\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "d:\CODES\Django\SMILE_BACKEND\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "d:\CODES\Django\SMILE_BACKEND\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "d:\CODES\Django\SMILE_BACKEND\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 79, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "d:\CODES\Django\SMILE_BACKEND\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "d:\CODES\Django\SMILE_BACKEND\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 82, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "d:\CODES\Django\SMILE_BACKEND\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 421, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such function: lwgeom_version
←[35;1mHTTP GET /api/v1/user/dentist/nearby/?latitude=69.764447962023&longitude=69.165280763008 500 [6.63, 127.0.0.1:13111]←[0m
```

Answer (score 0):

What database are you using?
The error message states that there is missing function **lwgeom_version**.

If you're using SQlite, the default database used by Django framework, you need to install [**SpatiaLite**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/gis/install/spatialite/). SpatiaLite adds spatial support for SQlite by incorporating LWGEOM, light-weight geometry library that is also used by PostGIS to add the support for Postgres database.

As for the spatial lookups, you're querying to find shortest distance calculations on points(with **srid=4326 or WGS84** standard) that are on a spherical/curved surface(earth). This needs calculating distance calculations between geometries using geographic coordinate systems and SpatiaLite appears to not have the capability to do that. Instead, you can use Postgres(i.e. PostGis) to add this capacity with better performance using methods such as `GeometryField.geography` .

You can refer to the complete GeoDjango model API [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/).

Answer (score 0):

This problem may occur when the Django version is too old, compared to the SpatiaLight version. SpatiaLight 5.0 does not support Django 3.2. Try updating Django to e.g. v4